# Is it possible to style <option> independently of <select> in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

The title is pretty self-explanatory, but essentially Chrome and Firefox are respecting my authority to style the `<select>` and `<option>` elements independently, whereas Safari is not. Is there a workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This was my workaround:

Instead of using a `<select>` box I used a `<ul>` and styled the list items. Then with a bit of JS/jQuery I added the `<select>` behavior. If this is an option for you, it will eliminate the browser support issues.

Comment: That would probably be better in all honesty. Seems like <select> is a very inflexible element anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Which safari version are you trying to get support for? Safari for windows got almost the same support like internet explorer 6.