# Apply style to specific select option only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to add a background color to a specific `option` of my `select` dropdown. Currently I am using the following, but it applies the color to all options under the dropdown. I have an option that is `''` and that is the one that I need to be red.

```
if (document.getElementById('agileteams' + x).value.length < 1 && array3[i]['Agile_Team'] == null) {
    document.getElementById('agileteams' + x).style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
```

I have tried adding a class to that option and changing the CSS but for some reason that does not seem to work.

Comment: what does your html look like

Comment: What you have should work, but be aware that styling `option` elements has very, *very* patchy support at best. It does seem to work for me in Chrome 47 though: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/frm3h4Lf/. If you need this behaviour to be reliable cross-browser I would suggest you use a plugin, such as Select2, which converts a `select` element to HTML which can be styled freely.

Comment: Since you're already using JS, something to keep in the back of your mind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34111287/3597276

Comment: are you open for jquery solution ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, for the info. The code does work to style all options within the drop down, but I want to style just the first option in the dropdown to be red.

Comment: @DinoMyte yes I would be open to a jquery solution.

Comment: @JordanDavis well the code in my fiddle example meets the condition you stated (`value.length < 1`) and only colours the background of the third option because of it. If you're seeing all the options being coloured, it's due to the styling inconsistencies of `option` elements that I mentioned.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah it must be a browser issue because I can see that the style attribute got added. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jquery version :

**Solution 1** : If you wish to just set the `background-color` on the initial load. This requires to iterate through each `option` inside `select` using jquery `each` function.

```
$('select option').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("value") == "" || $(this).attr("value") == undefined)   
     $(this).css("background-color","#FF0000"); // 'this' refers to the option element inside select
});
```

**Solution 2** : If you wish to just set the `background-color` when you select an `option`. This requires to delegate a change event on the `select`.

```
$('select').on("change", function(){
   if($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value") == "" || $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value") == undefined)  
     $(this).css("background-color","#FF0000"); // 'this' refers to the element select.
   else
   $(this).css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/dh0kxtLv/15/